# Renderer that can handle a lot of triangles and textures

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

**What would be the best method to render many triangles and textures?**

I want to a city in my game, that contains building that have thousands of triangles and up to 20 textures. At the moment the only method i know is rendering a batch for all triangle with the same texture. But that is really slow. I need something faster, but still simple.

Comment: At the moment, this is in danger of being closed.  What, specifically, is your question?  What have you tried?  Define 'slow' - perhaps you should profile your code, and see if that can spot some particular 'slow' areas to target.

Comment: Look at the bold text! That is my question. I mentioned that i tried drawing a batch for a all triangles with the same texture. And as i know that is much slower then other rendering methods.

Comment: http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/ ?

Comment: @Chorche: When he said "what have you tried?" he meant "show us some code that exhibits this behavior. What are you using to send vertex data: immediate mode, vertex arrays, buffer objects, or what?" In short: tell is more than some vague "it's slow" nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

- If your textures are small you can group them in an atlas texture and then you'll be batching more triangles in a single draw call.
- Maybe it's faster to eliminate the triangles that are not in view before batching and drawing them. If we're talking about lots of triangles this can make a difference.
- You said that you batch triangles. Are you using VBOs? If not you can try to use VBOs. It should be faster.

Also you can check the following links:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2093.html
- http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/sig97/perfopt.htm

You can also try to use a profiler for Open GL. It should also work in Java two because Java should interact with the hosts opengl driver.
 - http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debugging_Tools